# How do I get the session ID from an HTML response in postman

Tags: html, postman, cheerio

I am trying to get the `sess_id` from the html response in postman.

this is my test.

```
var test3 = cheerio(pm.response.text());
var variabile = test3.find('[pageId="/Security/SelectPaymentMethod?sess_id=SbyYFpsCefH3hVD3KNB7JwJ7VsYxdNBA1PKDbDJugmNZZyNZIJZeVdAb9H1neJfarNelwg6qXZx&amp;paymentMethodCode=VEC&amp;paymentMethodTypeCode=QTA&amp;environment=Test"]').val();
console.log(variabile('sess_id').val());
```

**HTML**

```
<link accesskey="1" pageId="/Security/SelectPaymentMethod?sess_id=HnapitQl8k9CBhiCkeaKPQP681rb8kFkHmgZKYRbxNw9SxMMcUtwpsKn5bA2s2drwwBzv3S3W1T&amp;paymentMethodCode=VEC&amp;paymentMethodTypeCode=QTA&amp;environment=Test">Verve eCash - Active</link>
```

in my console I get the response 
TypeError | `variable` is not a function

Comment: It's called "variabile". Do you use it as "variable" somewhere else in your code?

Comment: No I didn't use it anywhere else in the code

Comment: OK, so it prints "variabile" even there. In fact, you _are_ using it as a function, when you log it. Just do console.log(variable)

Answer (score 0):

This is a different and horrible way you *could* get that value:

```
let resData = xml2Json(pm.response.text());

let filteredData = resData.link.$.pageId.split('=')

console.log(filteredData[1].split('&')[0])
```

[image: Postman Console]

It's using `xml2Json` and passing that the response as text, it's then traversing down the data and splitting the `pageId` value. Not clean at all and I wouldn't use this anywhere other than figuring out a better solution but it's proving it *can* be done.

Comment: Thanks Danny. I will try this out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Danny for the effort.
Though I figured out another way.
I converted the xml to JSON first of all and made the test in JSON

```
let resp = xml2Json    (pm.response.text()),
ussdsessionId   = resp.page.navigation.link['2'].$.pageId;
console.log({ ussdsessionId });

pm.environment.set("sessionBank", ussdsessionId);
```